# Pass JSon Result to Controller Method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

Good Day! I am a newbie in asp.net mvc and needs to pass a JSonResult data to a method in the controller. In my **View**, I have this table:

```html
   <table id="tbl_orderItems" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>

                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Item Description</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            @if (TempData["listOrder"] != null)
            {
                foreach (var items in TempData["listOrder"] as List<ebms.ViewModels.OrderItems>)
                {  @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => items.Id, new { @id = "productId" })
                <tr>

                    <td id="productCode">@items.PRODUCT_CODE</td>
                    <td contenteditable="true" id="quantity">@items.QUANTITY_ORDERED
                        <input id="save" type="button" value="Save"  />
                    </td>
                    <td id="unit">@items.MEASUREMENT_NAME</td>
                    <td id="itemDesc">@items.ITEM_DESCRIPTION</td>
                    <td id="status">@items.tmpStatus</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new { id = items.Id },
                                        new { onclick = "return confirm('Are sure want to remove?');" })
                    </td>
                </tr>

                }

            }

        </table>
```

The values of this table came from another table. But one column, which is the Quantity has the value = 0 because it will be inputted in the table itself.

Therefore, I made **QUANTITY_ORDERED** column editable. It will then pass the value through this:

```js
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#save").prop("disabled", true);

        $("div").on('input', function () {
            $("#save").prop("disabled", false);
        });

        $("#save").click(function () {
            var modifiedQuanity = {};

            modifiedQuanity.Id = $("#productId").text();
            modifiedQuanity.QUANTITY_ORDERED = $("#quantity").text();


            $.post("/Sales/Save", modifiedQuanity, function (msg) {
                $("#save").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#msg").html("<strong>" + msg + "</strong>");
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

In my Controller, I have this JSonResult Method **Save** which is supposed to accept the value of QUANTITY_ORDERED from the view.

```html
        public JsonResult Save(ORDER_DETAILS obj)
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                ORDER_DETAILS existing = db.ORDER_DETAILS.Find(obj.PRODUCT_ID);
                existing.QUANTITY_ORDERED = obj.QUANTITY_ORDERED;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json("Order saved successfully!");
            }
        }
```

I then need to pass the JsonResult data to a Controller Method for the final saving.

But my problem is that, it doesn't seem to pass the value to **Save Method**.  And I can't figure out how to pass the JsonResult data to the Controller Method. Can someone help me out on this? What am I missing?

Comment: you are posting `Id` from browswer `modifiedQuanity.Id`, but using `PRODUCT_ID` in controller `ORDER_DETAILS existing = db.ORDER_DETAILS.Find(obj.PRODUCT_ID);`

Comment: @shakib I use **Id** in my view because it is the PK of the PRODUCT table where I get the values from. I then pass that ID but I use PRODUCT_ID because that's how it is called in the **ORDER_DETAILS** Model.

Comment: @shakib can you suggest another way of storing the content editable value and then passing that value to a controller?

Comment: you should change `modifiedQuanity.Id = $("#productId").text();` to `modifiedQuanity.PRODUCT_ID = $("#productId").text();` and see if the id is passed

Comment: @shakib I tried but it's still not passing anything. I think I'm missing something somewhere in the codes I just couldn't quite put a finger to it.

Comment: what happens when you set a breakpoint? Is "obj" null, or just some of the properties within it null?

Comment: @ADyson it doesn't go the JSonResult Method.

Comment: try replacing `$.post("/Sales/Save"` with `$.post('@Url.Action("Save", "Sales")'` - let MVC make sure the link to the action is correct. (I'm assuming the Save method is within a controller called SalesController).

Comment: @ADyson it worked! It now went to the **Save** JSonResult method. But I don't mean to save it into any table though, I now need to pass it to another method in the Controller.

Comment: what's your other method called? Is it within the same class or another? You can just call it the usual C# way `mymethod(obj);` Just change according to if it's in another class, or a static method or whatever.

Comment: @ADyson it's called AddOrder and it is not within the same class. I actually used a ViewModel for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace

```
$.post("/Sales/Save"
```

with

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Save", "Sales")'
```

This will let MVC ensure that the link to the controller action is correct.

Secondly, you're saying you want to pass the data to another method called "AddOrder" rather than saving it directly within your "Save" method.

I don't know what your method signature for this is, so I'll assume it's a static method within a class called "MyOtherClass" and accepts an ORDER_DETAILS instance as a parameter, like this:

```
public static void AddOrder(ORDER_DETAILS detsails)
{
   //... code here
}
```

In that case your "Save" method would be very simple, like this:

```
public JsonResult Save(ORDER_DETAILS obj)
{
   MyOtherClass.AddOrder(obj);
   return Json("Order saved successfully!");
}
```

So if the exact method details are different you'd need to adapt it to your precise situation.

Comment: just want to clarify, what is **.AddRecord** for?

Comment: sorry, misremembered your comment. It should be AddOrder shouldn't it :-) have edited the answer

Comment: Right. I was a bit confused :) This is my AddOrder method by the way, **public ActionResult AddOrder(OrderItems orderitem, ORDER_DETAILS details)**

Comment: you shouldn't really call another controller action from here. It's not good design. For a start it will try and return a View to you, which is no good when you're in an AJAX request. Secondly it's a bad separation of concerns. What you need is a secondary method (like in my example) which _both_ your controller actions can call, and do your processing in that method. Then the only real difference between "public JsonResult Save()" and "public ActionResult AddOrder" is that one returns JSON and the other returns a view. They both would call the same underlying method to save the data

Comment: What if I need to save multiple data to the **Save** method. I need my object to be a list or array?

Comment: `public static void AddOrder(List<ORDER_DETAILS> orderList)` would allow you to pass in a list containing 0 or more instances of  ORDER_DETAILS (using System.Collections.Generics.List class)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121722/discussion-between-kylie-irwin-and-adyson).

Comment: I am confused as to what I process I should put in the public static void method. I tried putting this **   using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                ORDER_DETAILS existing = db.ORDER_DETAILS.Find(quantity.PRODUCT_ID);
                existing.QUANTITY_ORDERED = quantity.QUANTITY_ORDERED;
   
            }** But it doesn't seem to get the PRODUCT_ID, it returns null for PRODUCT_ID

Comment: what is "quantity"? Is it an instance of the ORDER_DETAILS class?

Comment: Yes "quantity" is an instance of ORDER_DETAILS. It doesn't pass the value to another method because, PRODUCT_ID is null.

Comment: you aren't setting a variable called PRODUCT_ID when you create the object in your javascript. Change `modifiedQuanity.Id = $("#productId").text();` to `modifiedQuanity.PRODUCT_ID = $("#productId").text();`

Comment: It is now getting the PRODUCT_ID of the selected item. I tried it and I successfully created a record but the Quantity still wasn't passed. But when I tried executing it again, it now returns an error on this line in the static method: **ORDER_DETAILS existing = db.ORDER_DETAILS.Find(quantity.PRODUCT_ID);** because existing == null.

Comment: This was the error: **System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code**

Comment: presumably the product ID you passed in doesn't exist in the database then? It would help to know the exact message produced by the EntityCommandExecutionException, or if there was an inner exception. Maybe check the windows event log

Comment: It doesn't exist in the ORDER_DETAILS table yet but it is exists in the database on another table (PRODUCT).

Comment: well in that case trying to find it in the ORDER_DETAILS table as you're doing is clearly not going to work. You'd have to search in PRODUCT instead

Comment: I'm sorry I know we've been at it over and over again, I'm just confused as to what to put in the static void method and how to save data through that method.

Comment: I can't really tell you that without understanding your data structure. I thought you already had this code sorted out either in the "Save" example you gave, or in your existing "AddOrder" controller action. I assumed it was just a case of moving the code from the actions to the static method

Comment: I have managed to pass the data from the View to the Save method and I was also able to pass that to the static method. My concern is passing the data from the static method to the ActionResult. It's a bit blurry to me.

Comment: you don't. the ActionResult method passes data to the static method as well (separately, whenever it gets used). That way they share the same logic and you don't have to re-write it.

Comment: Is it not possible to pass the JSON to a method in the controller?

Comment: 1. you're not passing JSON, you're passing an object of type ORDER_DETAILS. The JSONResult is sent back to the user's web browser as the response from the ajax request. 2. You could call the other controller method from the Save method, but as I said before, it's really bad design to do it like that. If you remove or modify that action in  future then you'd have to modify the Save method too. If you use a shared method in the background which both controller methods use, then you remove that issue, and you only have to write code to save orders to the database in one place (but use it twice).